# Can I judge my status by android sensor, moving or motionless?

Tags: android, sensors

we can do many things by android sensor.  However, can I judge my status, such as moving, motionless.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to use Activity Recognition API  http://developer.android.com/training/location/activity-recognition.html .

Or you could read raw data from sensors to recognize patterns. But eventually you'll come the same functionality.

Comment: Thanks！ I will have a try！I prefer to read data from sensors to recognize patterns, but the algorithm is the key thing.